# How to populate the Cartesian product of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, cartesian-product

I have an array like this:

```
$string = array(
             "name" => "Mike",
             "country"=> "UK",
             "prefers" => array( "coffee", "milk", "bananas"),
             "age"=> "25"
             "children => array( Jack, Jill)
             );
```

How do I populate a "table" with all the parameters, to have a structure that would look like this :

```
array1 = (Mike, UK, coffee, 25, Jack)
array2 = (Mike, UK, milk, 25, Jack)
array3 = (Mike, UK, bananas, 25, Jack)
array4 = (Mike, UK, coffee, 25, Jill)
array5 = (Mike, UK, milk, 25, Jill)
array6 = (Mike, UK, bananas, 25, Jill)
```

Here, I would need to have a 1*1*3*1*2 = 6 rows and 5 columns structure, no empty cells.

Comment: I believe the op is asking how to create the cartesian product (i.e. cross join) of all values in the JSON array and store the transposed results in PHP arrays...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I messed up, first time around, because my solutions didn't generate all permutations. Here's another go, which should be a correct generic solution:

```
function arrayCrossProduct( array $data ) {
  $rowCount = 1; // keep track of total rows we need to generate

  // the reference is just used for convenience to cast to and reset the array
  foreach( $data as &$datum ) {
    $datum = (array) $datum; // cast to array
    $rowCount *= count( $datum ); // multiply total rows with current element count
    reset( $datum ); // reset the array, just to be sure
  }

  $result = array();
  while( $rowCount-- > 0 ) {
    $row = array();
    foreach( $data as &$datum ) {  // reference necessary to keep track of array pointer
      $row[] = current( $datum ); // generate new row
    }
    $result[] = $row; // add row to result

    // find the first element that is advanceable
    foreach( $data as &$datum ) {  // reference necessary to keep track of array pointer
      next( $datum );

      // if it advanced/not at the end: break
      if( !is_null( key( $datum ) ) ) {
        break;
      }

      reset( $datum ); // else rewind the array and continue
    }
  }

  return $result;
}
```

<sup>You can view it [working online](https://3v4l.org/4EtIF), with some sample data and some formatted output.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague, but if it is what I believe it to be then the answer would be to use `json_encode($string,TRUE);`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
   <?php
  // Print the array in a nice form
  function print_r2 ($Array) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($Array);
    echo "</pre>"; }


$array1[] = array(Mike, UK, coffee, 25, Jack);
$array1[] = array(Mike, UK, milk, 25, Jack);
$array1[] = array(Mike, UK, bananas, 25, Jack);
$array1[] = array(Mike, UK, coffee, 25, Jill);
$array1[] = array(Mike, UK, milk, 25, Jill);
$array1[] = array(Mike, UK, bananas, 25, Jill);




foreach($array1 as $array6){
    //first create multidimentional arrays to separate duplicates using values as keys.
if(!in_array($array6[2],$parray[$array6[0]][$array6[1]][$array6[3]][prefers])) {
                        $parray[$array6[0]][$array6[1]][$array6[3]][prefers][]=$array6[2];}

if(!in_array($array6[4],$parray[$array6[0]][$array6[1]][$array6[3]][children])) {
                        $parray[$array6[0]][$array6[1]][$array6[3]][children][]=$array6[4];}

}
print_r2($parray);

foreach($parray as $name => $value){
    $array[name] = $name;
        foreach($value as $country => $value2) {
            $array[country] = $country;
                foreach($value2 as $age => $value3  ){
                    $array[prefers] = $value2[$age][prefers];
                    $array[age] = $age;
                    $array[children] = $value2[$age][children];
                }

        }

}
        print_r2($array);
//OR
echo json_encode($array);
                            ?>
```

Comment: This is a brute force method. Didn't check yours but I have something like this also. Looking for a universal method that would work on any JSON that is being loaded. There sure must be a system for solving this kind of problems.

Comment: Ah ha!  Revised question.  Yay!  The code above does the exact opposite of your goal.  It looks as though you want to go from a relational array to a flat table.  I will follow up with another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more like what you are looking for with your revised question.  I just appended the opposite goal on the bottom of my original answer.

```
       <?php
  // Print the array in a nice form
  function print_r2 ($Array) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($Array);
    echo "</pre>"; }


$array1[] = array(Mike, UK, coffee, 25, Jack);
$array1[] = array(Mike, UK, milk, 25, Jack);
$array1[] = array(Mike, UK, bananas, 25, Jack);
$array1[] = array(Mike, UK, coffee, 25, Jill);
$array1[] = array(Mike, UK, milk, 25, Jill);
$array1[] = array(Mike, UK, bananas, 25, Jill);




foreach($array1 as $array6){
    //first create multidimentional arrays to separate duplicates using values as keys.
if(!in_array($array6[2],$parray[$array6[0]][$array6[1]][$array6[3]][prefers])) {
                        $parray[$array6[0]][$array6[1]][$array6[3]][prefers][]=$array6[2];}

if(!in_array($array6[4],$parray[$array6[0]][$array6[1]][$array6[3]][children])) {
                        $parray[$array6[0]][$array6[1]][$array6[3]][children][]=$array6[4];}

}
print_r2($parray);

foreach($parray as $name => $value){
    $array[name] = $name;
        foreach($value as $country => $value2) {
            $array[country] = $country;
                foreach($value2 as $age => $value3  ){
                    $array[prefers] = $value2[$age][prefers];
                    $array[age] = $age;
                    $array[children] = $value2[$age][children];
                }

        }

}
        print_r2($array);
//OR
echo json_encode($array);

echo"<br />";echo"<br />";
//** now backwards**
echo"<br />";
echo"<br />";
$no=1;
    foreach($array[children] as $children ) {
foreach($array[prefers] as $prefers ) {

    print("array".$no." = (".$array[name].", ".$array[country].",".$prefers.",".$array[age].",".$children.")<br />\n");

    $no++;
}
}







                            ?>
```